# Window resize moves Fixed Positioned element, any way this can be avoided?

Tags: html, css

I'm new to web coding and what I am trying to achieve is to have my logo element scroll with the background, which is why I needed the fixed position, and, on the same time, get it to keep its position, which means that I don't want it visible when I resize the window to a very small size, so when the window will be smaller part of the logo should not be visible up to the point that logo cannot be seen at all, due to window size still. In other words set a size as a lower limit, below which the logo stops following the fixed position rule.

```html
    <div id="main">
            
            <div id="logo">
            <a href="MyIndex.html"><img src="Logo.png" width="355.2px" height="148.8px" onMouseOver="this.src='Logo2.png'" onMouseOut="this.src='Logo.png'" /></a>
            </div><!--ends logo-->
```

```css
#main {
        margin:0 auto;
        height:1200px;
        width:1200px;
        background-image:url(Background.png);
    }
    
    #logo {
        position:fixed;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-177.6px;
        width:355.2px;
        height:148.8px;
    }
```

Comment: Nothing *moves* for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nothing moves for me too and if you want your logo to be not shown when re-sizing to a smaller screen, then use css media queries to change the logo fixed position and then when scrolling it will scroll and not be visible also you can put display on none

Comment: Can you post me a code for that? As I don't know about media queries 'cos I have been around these languages only for a week now.

Comment: for screen width between for instance 768px and 1024px
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { 
/* 
   styling goes here
 */
}
 you can take a look in here for more examples:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I meant; after long time I came back to this thread and I realized that I wasn't precise enough, and this is exactly what I meant, so I edited the question , thanks again!